# is it possible to replace more than one different string at one go using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to replace string values and i know to replace the value one by one like this but i want to replace the name and country at one go is it possible?

```
const t = 'hello world I am <name> and i live in this <country>'
const t1 = t.replace('<name>', 'Xanderous');
const t2 = t1.replace('<country>', 'India');
console.log(t2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `t1` is returning a string, you can again call `replace` on it.

Example:

```js
const t = 'hello world I am <name> and i live in this <country>'
const t1 = t.replace('<name>', 'Xanderous').replace('<country>', 'India');
console.log(t1);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose you can use interpolation in JavaScript.

```js
let name = "Xanderous";
let country = "India";
let extraInfo = "I love traveling!";
const dynamicReplacedString = `hello world I am ${name} and i live in this ${country}. And ${extraInfo}`;
console.log(dynamicReplacedString);
```

I hope it will help you.